How can I prevent my multistep form from being submitted?
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
 COLLECTION_ID_USERS,
 DATABASE_ID,
 databases,
 } from "../../appwriteConfig";
 import { ID } from "appwrite";
 import {
  FaRegPaperPlane,
  FaArrowLeftLong,
  FaArrowRightLong,
  } from "react-icons/fa6";
 import { FileUpload, ParentInfo, StudentInfo } from "..";
 import * as yup from "yup";

 import "./multistepForm.css";

 const MultistepForm = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
   stdName: "",
   stdMiddleName: "",
   stdSurname: "",
   stdGender: "",
   stdPOB: "",
   stdDOB: "",
   fatherName: "",
   motherName: "",
  });

  const handleNavigation = (action) => {
   if (action === "next" && step < FormHeaders.length - 1) {
   setStep(step + 1);
  } else if (action === "back" && step > 0) {
  setStep(step - 1);
 } else if (action === "submit") {
  alert("Submission completed");
 }
};
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

let response = await databases.createDocument(
  DATABASE_ID,
  COLLECTION_ID_USERS,
  ID.unique(),
  formData
);

console.log("Created", response);
if (step !== FormHeaders.length - 1) {
  handleNavigation("next");
} else {
  handleNavigation("submit");
}
};
const FormHeaders = [
"Student Information",
"Parent Information",
"Upload Files",
];

const StepDisplay = () => {
switch (step) {
  case 0:
    return <StudentInfo formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
  case 1:
    return <ParentInfo formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
   default:
     return <FileUpload formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />;
}
};
return (
<div className="form">
  <h2 className="form-title">Online Application</h2>
  <div className="progressbar">
    <div
      style={{
        width: step === 0 ? "33.3%" : step === 1 ? "66.6%" : "100%",
      }}
    ></div>
  </div>
  <div className="form-container">
    <h1 className="form-header">{FormHeaders[step]}</h1>
    <div className="form-body">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} action="#">
        {StepDisplay()}
        <div className="form-footer">
          {step !== 0 && (
            <button
              type="button"
              className="form-btn btn"
              onClick={() => handleNavigation("back")}
            >
              <FaArrowLeftLong />
            </button>
          )}
          <button className="form-btn btn next" type="submit">
            {step === FormHeaders.length - 1 ? (
              <h2 className="next-page">
                Submit
                <i>
                  <FaRegPaperPlane />
                </i>
              </h2>
            ) : (
              <h2 className="next-page">
                Next Page
                <i>
                  <FaArrowRightLong />
                </i>
              </h2>
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
};

export default MultistepForm;

I am trying to submit my multistep form in reactJS, but every time I do so, I notice in the console that the form is being submitted three times, which means that every time I click on the "Next" button, the form is being submitted. That means that the "Next" button is still having the action of submitting.
I would really need help troubleshooting the handleSubmit function so that the form gets submitted when the "Submit" button is clicked. Thanks in advance.
Also, I wanted to know how I can clear the form data and go back right at the beginning once the form is submitted.

There is no console.log() on the final submit logic, but rather an alert() message. The only console.log() occurs at the top of your handleSubmit() function which runs every time regardless of which step:
let response = await databases.createDocument(
  DATABASE_ID,
  COLLECTION_ID_USERS,
  ID.unique(),
  formData
);

console.log("Created", response);

If you want this piece of code to only run on the final submit, you will need to place it where the alert("Submission completed"); part of your handleNavigation() function is, since that is the only part that only runs on the third submit.
My guess is that you want to be saving a piece of form data into your state using setFormData() rather than doing some database create document thing at the top of your handleSubmit().
Also, one more tip, when you want to set state based on the previous state, you would typically want to pass a function in the state setter function like this:
setStep((prevStep) => prevStep + 1);

The function will get the previous value as an argument, and this will stop certain bugs that may occur when using the state (step) variable itself.
Also, you are duplicating some of your step checking logic. For instance, you don't render the "Back" button if the step is 0, but in the click handler you again check to make sure the step is not 0. You do a similar thing for the "Next" button, where you only call handleNavigation("next") if the step is less than an array length, but then in handleNavigation() you check to make sure the step is less than that array length again.

@JeanMako Glad I could help! If this answered your question, you can "accept" the answer above using the checkmark.

Do you know how to convert a file into a URL in React?

@JeanMako I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Do you mean like down loading an image/file in a React app? Or do you mean like routing to different pages in React?

I am trying to submit a form to my Appwite database, and the form contains some input files, I want to submit them to the data with the URL type.
